# Find the values $x \in\mathbb{R}$ where series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the values $x \in\mathbb{R}$ where series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converges.

I'm pretty sure that only values where $x\in(0,1)$ allow the series to converge because values within that range will shrink to  0 as n approaches infinity. Any value larger than 1 will create increasingly large summands and the series will eventually reach infinity.

Comment: This is a simple example of a Lambert series. The region of convergence is inside the unit circle in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering for $x\geq 0$. For $x\in [0,1)$, we have
$$\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \leq x^n,$$
and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ converges, so indeed the initial series converge. For $x> 1$, $x^n/(1+x^n)\to 1>0$ and so the series diverges. For $x=1$, $x^n/(1+x^n)=1/2$ and the series diverges as well.

Answer (score 0):

By n-th term test for divergence, a necessary condition for a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ to converge is $\lim_\limits{n\to 0}a_n=0$.

Here we have $a_n=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$

$\implies \lim_\limits{n\to 0}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=0$, otherwise the series diverges.

$\implies \frac{1}{1+\lim_\limits{n\to 0}\frac{1}{x^n}}=0$

$\implies \lim_\limits{n\to 0}x^n=0$

$\implies x \in (-1,1)$

So, the series diverges for all $x$ outside the open interval centered at origin.

This condition is necessary, although not sufficient, we need to try other tests (Ratio, Root tests etc.) for sufficiency (to test if the series converges for all points inside the open interval).